# Duplicate materials in Mfg Details, epicor

Tags: erp, epicorerp

I am getting duplicate materials in Mfg Details when I run the GetDetails Method.  Anyone came across this in Epicor?

Comment: Could you give more details of what you are trying to do and perhaps sample of the code that is returning the details you aren't expecting.

Comment: Managed to resolve it.  Two revisions with same effective date were causing the duplication of materials

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to fix it.  There were two revisions with the same Effective Date, both revisions were approved. This is where the duplicate in materials came from...